# PHP session_start() not working if not login wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

If I have log in wp admin then my session is working but if I have no login in WP-admin then session is not working. How can I solve that?

```
<?php 
session_start();

global $post;
if( $post->ID == 22 ) : 
    session_unset(); 
    echo "Login Page";
else : 
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

remove session_start from your code.

add this code in your functions.php:

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'myInitSession' );

function initSession(){ 
    if( !session_id() ){
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. is this server related issue? Because same code is working in staging site.

Comment: Try to deactivate plugins, to check if there is no plugin that block sessions.